# Audio loss on converting HikVision using ffmpeg

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, codec

I am cropping HiKVision source mp4 video to small bits using command line tool. But the resultant videos dont have audio. I am able to play the source videos on WiMP (after installing hikvision codecs). But not on MPC (it plays without audio). So I am assuming it boils down to the codecs.

How do I get audio from the source clips into the output. If I can include the codec, how can I do that? Will I need to recompile it from source (the last thing I would want to do)

This is the ffmpeg out:

```
ffmpeg -f h264 -i New_DVR_ETNOW_21-22.mp4 -codec copy -fflags genpts -y -f mp4 thefile.mp4

ffmpeg version N-51433-g551f683 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Mar 28 2013 21:52:57 with gcc 4.8.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 22.101 / 52. 22.101
  libavcodec     55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
  libavformat    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
  libavdevice    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
  libavfilter     3. 48.105 /  3. 48.105
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
[h264 @ 028e3220] non-existing PPS referenced
[h264 @ 028e3220] non-existing PPS 3 referenced
[h264 @ 028e3220] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 028e3220] no frame!
[h264 @ 028e2d00] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5000000 microseconds
[h264 @ 028e2d00] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, h264, from 'New_DVR_ETNOW_21-22.mp4':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Baseline), yuv420p, 352x288, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 50 tbc
Output #0, mp4, to 'thefile.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.0.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 352x288, q=2-31, 25 fps, 1200k tbn, 1200k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=89975 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=  116729kB time=00:59:58.98 bitrate= 265.7kbits/s
video:116088kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.552460%
```

Sample file for reference: http://www.datafilehost.com/get.php?file=cc992777

Comment: Can you provide a sample file? This is [FFmpeg bug #3566](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3566). The original author did not respond to questions, so any comments from you may be helpful.

Comment: same result with updated ffmpeg?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard - Yes. It has audio. Testing it with mediainfo, I got this info. One Audio stream, MPEG AUDIO (LATM).